# INSERT INTO with use CASE - sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, if-statement, case, sql-insert

I have a problem with syntax.
I need use IF in sqlite, and I replace IF - CASE.
My statement doesn't work, I don't know, what is wrong?

```
CASE
WHEN EXISTS(
  SELECT sql
    FROM sqlite_master 
    WHERE name = 'TEST_TABLE' AND
          type = 'table' AND
          sql LIKE '%aaaa%'
)THEN
  INSERT INTO atabela_new(id, idMain, idHistory, aNew)
  SELECT id, idMain, idHistory, aNew  FROM a_tabela
ELSE
  INSERT INTO atabela_new(id, idMain, idHistory)
  SELECT id, idMain, idHistory FROM a_tabela;
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: In SQLite, you can use CASE inside an expression, not this way! What do you really pretend to do?

Comment: I want to do 'INSERT' if the condition is true or another 'INSERT', if the condition is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the default for `aNew` is NULL:

```
INSERT INTO atabela_new(id, idMain, idHistory, aNew)
SELECT id, 
       idMain, 
       idHistory,  
       CASE
           WHEN EXISTS
              (SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'TEST_TABLE' AND type = 'table' AND sql LIKE '%aaaa%')
           THEN aNew 
           ELSE NULL
       END
FROM a_tabela
```

Otherwise you'll need to put that logic in your application code.

Answer (score -3):

If all you want to do is insert one statement if true or another statement if false why not just use an if statement?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'TEST_TABLE' AND type = 'table' AND sql LIKE '%aaaa%')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO atabela_new(id, idMain, idHistory, aNew) SELECT id, idMain, idHistory, aNew FROM a_tabela
END
ELSE
    INSERT INTO atabela_new(id, idMain, idHistory) SELECT id, idMain, idHistory FROM a_tabela;
END
```

Comment: ...because SQLite does not have an IF statement of that form. That's the point of the question, how to do what you have written in a syntax that is valid for SQLite.